# Copy SQL table into a new one, only for records that are newer than a given date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table with many records, and want to create an identical table in its structure, but in its data I want to copy only records with a value that is older than `2019-07-01 00:08:39` , under `LastModified` (type is `timestamp`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [CTAS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html) syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE tab2
AS
SELECT *
FROM tab1
WHERE LastModified > '2019-07-01 00:08:39'
```